# JSON Schema - Deny the use of an object if value is not correct

Tags: json

I am trying to figure out how I can prevent the use of "MoveToArchiveSection" when BatchChangeOperation is used and operation not equal MOVE.

```
{
    "BatchChangeOperation": {
        "oneOf": [
            { "operation": "DELETE" },
            { "operation": "UPDATE" },
            { "operation": "EXTRACT" },
            { "operation": "MOVE", 
                "required": [ "MoveToArchiveSection" ] 
            }
        ]
    },
    "MoveToArchiveSection": {
        "TargetArchiveSectionId": {
        },
        "required": [
            "TargetArchiveSectionId" 
        ]
    }
}
```

You can see I have set required "MoveToArchiveSection" when operation equal "MOVE", but that does not prevent the use of "MoveToArchiveSection" when operation equal "UPDATE", "EXTRACT" or "DELETE". "MoveToArchiveSection" should always be required when operation equal "MOVE".

My JSON input should look like this when Operation equal MOVE:

```
{
    "BatchChangeOperation": {
        "operation": "MOVE"
    },
    "MoveToArchiveSection": {
        "TargetArchiveSectionId": "bla"
    }
}
```

My JSON input should look like this when Operation equal UPDATE:

```
{
    "BatchChangeOperation": {
        "operation": "UPDATE"
    }
}
```

Your help is very much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want your jsonschema has to look something like this (using enums for MOVE, DELETE, EXTRACT, etc...)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "BatchChangeOperation": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "operation": {
              "enum": [
                "DELETE"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "operation": {
              "enum": [
                "MOVE"
              ]
            },
            "MoveToArchiveSection": {
              "properties": {
                "TargetArchiveSectionId": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "TargetArchiveSectionId"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "MoveToArchiveSection"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

then this json

```
{
  "BatchChangeOperation": {
    "operation": "MOVE"
  }
}
```

doesn't validate, but this

```
{
  "BatchChangeOperation": {
    "operation": "MOVE",
    "MoveToArchiveSection": {
      "TargetArchiveSectionId": "blabla"
    }
  }
}
```

does.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please take a look at my changes. I only added what I want my JSON input file to look like. Is it possible?